# How to edit sunsets & sunrises to achieve a soft, peachy-pink color over the usual orange?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, photo-editing, sunset, sunrise

Can you please help me figure out how to achieve the soft, peachy-pink coloring on the sand and light in the images below?

Usually, my sunsets/sunrises are much more orange and when I try to edit, I end up too pink-reddish.

[image: Peachy Pink Sunrise here]

Comment: "Shoot 15 to 30 minutes earlier, and underexpose"... oh wait, that isn't an editing technique....

Comment: Are you shooting RAW so you have more bits to work with in your edits?

Answer (score 1):

*This answer is: Thoughts on how to shoot sunsets so you end up with the best capture of the actual colors present in the scene BEFORE  you do any post production.*

The best way to get the "soft, peachy-pink coloring" is to shoot when the colors are soft, peachy-pink.

***Every sunset has different colors and qualities***.

Shoot dozens of shots of all exposure combinations from very under exposed on up.  start shooting early and shoot until colors are gone.( *the colors can change rapidly* ) Pretty soon you will get a feel for how much under-exposure is needed for rich saturated colors.

**The goal is to capture the colors with your camera and not change it with editing.**

Comment: _The goal is to capture the colors with your camera and not change it with editing._ But the OP's stated goal **is** to edit the colors. It might not be your goal when capturing sunsets, but it appears to be theirs. There is an entire market of optical glass or resin filters to enhance or punch up orange or pink or even blue tones for sunsets. Those filters alter the colors of the scene going into the camera. What's the difference if somebody were to instead emulate the effect in post?

Comment: Starting with a different exposure will help achieve the goal, so this answer is helpful IMO. The examples were exposed for the land, not the sky (sky is overexposed). Most people expose a sunset for the sky, which helps create the orange. Lightening an underexposed sky in post to get the desired result is not the best solution.

Comment: @scottbb I  could postulate and lecture about MY opinion on when a Photograph ceases to be a photograph and is turned into a Digital image through Post Production editing.  BUT i wont. *Yes i own a full set of graduated color cokin filters*.

Comment: Fair enough. I only commented to point out that OP asked **how** to edit to get the desired colors. Regardless, you are correct, in that it's much easier to do if the colors are there to begin with.